# FTP ASCII mode skipping blank line when converting to CRLF

Tags: linux, windows, ftp

We're transfering a file from linux to windows.  As expected some LF (0x0a) are being converted to CRLF (0x0D 0x0A), but there's at least once instance - a blank line - that is not being converted:

[image: raw file]

[image: bad ascii file]

Comment: Can you transfer it in binary and do a `unix2dos` on it when it arrives?

Comment: Maybe you can run the FTP server on the other box - Filezilla is great and free and there is a Filezilla server too.

Comment: Btw, you could equally run `unix2dos` on it whilst it is on the Linux platform prior to FTP'ing in binary.

Comment: I'm open to work arounds but I'm mostly interested in why this is happening to begin with.

Comment: I'm guessing a bug in the server. Try a different client.